# Add FragmentActivity inside a tab on Android ActionBar tab.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I have a tab bar view created using FragmentActivity. I also have separate sliding ViewPager, created using FragmentActivity. I just need to add this sliding ViewPager inside one of the tab on the my tab bar view. Basically I need to have sliding view inside one of the tab (not the swipe view with tab). I am using Android 4.0 and above.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot "Add FragmentActivity inside a tab on Android ActionBar tab". Activities-inside-of-activities has been deprecated for ~30 months and never supported action bar tabs.

One possible alternative is for you to change your `ViewPager` to be inside a `Fragment`, instead of a `FragmentActivity`. If the `ViewPager` is using a fragment-based `PagerAdapter`, it can do so using nested fragments -- use `getChildFragmentManager()` when creating your `PagerAdapter`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrating a `ViewPager` in a fragment and using nested fragment for pages.